# Swift TableViewController - Top Cell Goes Under Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to learn iOS dev with xCode 8.2  and swift 3.

I have a navigation view that embeds a tab view that has a normal View in one tab and a TableView in the other. In both tabs, the top is always cut off by the navigation controller. How do I fix that so the data is displayed below the navigation bar?

Also, when I removed the navigation bar, I noticed that the data was still going under the transparent bar at the top that has the time and stuff.

Comment: Did you try setting the top margin to `SafeArea`? And if it's still under, then add a margin for instance `20`.

Comment: I can't find anything that lets me do that. I have autoLayout enabled, but it doesnt let me set contrains. I tried usign the button at the bottom that looks like this |-[]-|, but i couldnt adjust it

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of constraints of tableView?